# Using YAML anchors in Ansible role tasks file

Tags: ansible

I am trying to create an ansible role tasks file that has several repeated sections in it, and I'd like to take advantage of YAML's anchor feature, which allows data to be shared across a file. In my actual file, I have 3 or 4 properties that need to be exactly the same across a dozen tasks in my file, so anchors seem like the perfect solution. Here is my setup:

## hosts.ini

```
localhost connection=local
```

## test.yml

```
---
- name: test
  hosts: localhost
  roles:
    - test
```

## roles/test/tasks/main.yml

```
---
foo: &foo
  msg: 'this is a test'

- name: Test message
  debug:
    <<: *foo
```

I expect that the properties of the `foo` dictionary should be spread into the `debug` dictionary, resulting in a structure like

```
{
  "name": "Test message",
  "debug": {
    "msg": "this is a test"
  }
}
```

However, I am instead getting this error message when I try to run the playbook:

```
λ ansible-playbook -i hosts.ini test.yml
ERROR! Syntax Error while loading YAML.
  did not find expected key

The error appears to have been in '~/ansible-test/roles/test/tasks/main.yml': line 5, column 1, but may
be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.

The offending line appears to be:


- name: Test message
^ here
```

Is it possible to use YAML anchors in ansible role task files? Or is there a better way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Is it possible to use YAML anchors in ansible role task files? Or is there a better way to accomplish this?

Sure, but what's going on is that the YAML document you created isn't legal ansible; you can't just use any arbitrary top-level key and expect good outcomes -- it has nothing to do with YAML anchors

What you want is:

```
- set_fact:
    foo: &foo
      msg: this is a test

- name: Test message
  debug:
    <<: *foo
```

You don't have to use `set_fact`, any "non executable" task will do, and you can also use a `when:` to keep that from even running because it's just the YAML structure that's important. You can also create that structure in a `vars:` block of some other task, even if the task doesn't use the var