# how do I create a duplicated node in ansible roles

Tags: ansible, yaml

I am trying to automate the same credential for cyberark to make different queries using Ansible. You can see the same details repeat and repeat again for:

```
username: user
password: p@ssword
server: abc.com
```

i have written a module for cyberark to handle all functions like retrieving passwords, creating new accounts, check account existence, etc

While I know it is possible for yaml to create duplicated nodes and modifying its value. I have tested the following code is working fine in a single playbook:

```
  hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: no

  vars:
          cyberArkUsername: user
          cyberArkPassword: p@ssword
          server: abc.com

          Details: &basicCA
                  state:
                  username: "{{ cyberArkUsername }}"
                  password: "{{ cyberArkPassword }}"
                  server: "{{ server }}"
                  account:
                          accountname:

  tasks:
          - name: check exist
            CyberArkModule:
                    <<: *basicCA
                    state: check
                    account:
                            accountname: test_CA
```

However when i try to migrate this logic to a role It doesn't work at all

var declared in vars/main.yml

```
CADetails: &login
        state:
        server: abc.com
        username: user
        password: p@ssword
        account:
```

when I try to run tasks/main.yml

```
- name: fetch password
  CyberarkModule:
    <<: *login
    state: check
    account:
        accountname: test_CA
```

it will prompt

> Syntax Error while loading YAML.   found undefined alias

what's the right way to save the few lines of code and duplication?

Comment: Yaml anchors and aliases must be used in the same file.

Comment: Is there any way to declare vars in the tasks/main.yml page?

Comment: I have even tried to declare different modifications in the vars/main.yml page. I don’t know how to apple the vars to CyberarkModule: in the tasks/main.yml

Comment: You could fool Ansible by writing a task that would never play, define the anchor there and reuse it as an alias elsewhere in the file. But that's ugly. Why don't you simply modify your custom module so that it reads those info from environment variable if they exist? Moreover, are you aware that there are already collections available for interaction with cyberark?

Answer (score 0):

With the hint of the following page, I managed to declare the var with set_fact.
Thank you @Zeitounator all the same!

[Using YAML anchors in Ansible role tasks file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55518577/using-yaml-anchors-in-ansible-role-tasks-file)